# Adding textViews in a for loop

Tags: android, android-layout

```
      scrollview = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.detailedScrollView);


  for (Quotation quotation : object.quotes){

          TextView quote = new TextView(this);
          quote.setText(quotation.getQuote());
          quote.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
          scrollview.addView(quote);


      }
```

Let's say there are three quotes, then I want to have three textViews. However, the code above crashes my app. Any obvious mistakes? Here's the error I'm getting:

```
11-06 17:35:53.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1430): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
```

Comment: What's the logcat say? What's the error you're getting?

Comment: 11-06 17:35:53.214: E/AndroidRuntime(1430): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
Ah scrollview can only have one child? I guess I need to put everything in a linearLayout then into the scrollview?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't add views directly inside a scrollview. A scrollview can only contain a single layout object. What you have to do is to add a linearlayout in your scrollview, then add the textview to the linearlayout

Answer (score 3):

Layout container for a view hierarchy that can be scrolled by the user, allowing it to be larger than the physical display. A ScrollView is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place one child in it containing the entire contents to scroll; this child may itself be a layout manager with a complex hierarchy of objects. A child that is often used is a LinearLayout in a vertical orientation, presenting a vertical array of top-level items that the user can scroll through.

The TextView class also takes care of its own scrolling, so does not require a ScrollView, but using the two together is possible to achieve the effect of a text view within a larger container. [Please more detail](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

With best regards, 
Psycho

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a "LinearLayout" (or "RelativeLayout") inside ScrollView.
Say you have the layout xml as follows:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"        
    >       
  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And now you want to add the 'TextView' programmatically, which is as follows:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout =(LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.linearlayout1);
for (Quotation quotation : object.quotes){
     TextView quote = new TextView(this);
     quote.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
     quote.setPadding(4, 0, 4, 0);    //left,top,right,bottom
     quote.setText(quotation.getQuote());          
     linearLayout.addView(quote);
}
```